# What taxes do new subcontractors pay?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I started a job a few weeks ago and I was wondering how do I know how much to pay on my taxes if I'm a subcontractor.

The contractor who got me on he said that I would get a 1099, but I just want to make sure I pay my taxes on time as this is my first time being a subcontractor.

Comment: Dupe of http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/19195/new-to-working-as-an-independent-contractor-what-do . Assuming no payroll or other withholding, basically you **estimate** what your tax will be -- income plus "self-employment" (replaces FICA) -- and **pay each quarter** as defined by the tax system, which is slightly different than the normal calendar. You don't have to estimate exactly right; as long as you get **within 10%** and pay the remainder by the (unextended) filing deadline, there's no penalty. States have a similar procedure, except those with no income tax at all.